# Remove / Merge tags

Tags: support, tagging

Already I see some tag-sprawl. Eg

- List(12) Lists(0) (other tags are usually in plural)
- Documents(4) Document(0)

Is there a way to either delete or merge these tags, or flag as redundant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just flag the post and give some detail. We'll also probably create [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) for them.

Comment: what all 12 of them? :-)

Comment: Whatever's required to keep things tidy! Have a look now you're a mod. Stack Overflow has plenty.

Comment: Another question, do we keep the plural or singular version? Ex: document-library or document-libraries?

Comment: @KitMenke: I don't have a clear idea on that, so I referred to Meta SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41501/tagging-as-singular-or-plural. Doesn't really matter but probably singular.